# Should I include different types of result listing pages in my xml sitemap?

Tags: seo, sitemap

Say I have an articles section. It can be  filtered by **tag** `(/articles/tag/detectives)`, by **author** `(/articles/author-url)` and also through **regular pagination**, with the recent first `(/articles?page=2)`.

*In addition to the main articles to which they point, Which of these filtered listings URLs should I include in my sitemap?*

On one hand I have read that any url that I'd like appearing in search results should be included in the sitemap. I would like both tag and author listing pages to come up in search results if possible.

[Should paginated sites be included in sitemap?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59542/should-paginated-sites-be-included-in-sitemap)

On the other hand, I have read on SO that it might be preferable to just put the main detail pages in the sitemap and to omit the listing pages. Quote:

> "Maybe then I'd omit the listing pages altogether. Doesn't sound like
>   they have any real content on them and it could detract from the
>   details pages - which is presumably where you actually want your users
>   to go"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696836/should-i-include-paginated-results-in-my-sitemap-xml

Can anybody more experienced than myself provide clarification or guidance on this? 
Any official sources would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommended you to put a rel='canonical' from all the similar pages to the main page of the group and then include this main page into your sitemap.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Marian, could you elaborate on why you recommend this?

Comment: Your pages of tags, authors and pagination are duplicates for search engines, but may be useful for visitors. To solve this kind of issue Google recommends to use rel='canonical'.

Comment: I have since found this page (don't know why I didn't see it before), but it answers the question in a bit more detail: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32581/question-about-paginated-based-urls-and-category-urls-with-xml-sitemaps?rq=1

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox Yes, good answer too.